Add a fixed amount of minutes to a Java LocalTime in a for-loop until midnight without causing an infinite loop
Given a LocalTime add n minutes to it untill midnight and print those times to console. Example:
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalTime start    = LocalTime.of(10, 12, 0);
    LocalTime midnight = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59);

    for (LocalTime t = start; t.isBefore(midnight); t = t.plusMinutes(30)) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}

Expected:
10:12
10:42
11:12
11:42
12:12
...
...
21:42
22:12
22:42
23:12
23:42

The above results in an infinite loop. How to avoid it?

Adding 30 minutes to 23:42 will just wrap around to 00:12 which is still before midnight. Maybe check for midnight minus 30 mins as the last valid time.

The slightly hacky solution: subtract 30 minutes from LocalTime.MIDNIGHT (which is 00:00, so you will get 23:30). Iterate until you reach or pass that time and also print the time you arrive at (in your case 23:42).

It’ an interesting problem, and I am delighted to see that it has given a couple of good answers already. We’re really missing a way to detect overflow when adding to (or subtracting from) a LocalTime. Like a plusMinutesExact method (name inspired from Math.addExact and other methods).

As you are observing, t.isBefore(midnight) will not suffice, because nearly every LocalTime value will satisfy that condition.
What you really want is to determine whether adding 30 minutes will cause the time to be less than the current value of t:
for (LocalTime t = start; t.isBefore(t.plusMinutes(30)); t = t.plusMinutes(30)) {

That will stop the loop when adding 30 minutes to t results in a value which is less than t itself, which can only happen when the minutes addition wraps around at the end of a day.
But it’s not perfect, because it won’t print the last value of the day.  You can do that with a second variable that tracks the previous time:
LocalTime previous = null;
for (LocalTime t = start;
     previous == null || previous.isBefore(t);
     previous = t, t = t.plusMinutes(30)) {

    System.out.println(t);
}


It's easy when someone explains it to you, but I wouldn't have thought of it myself. I think that's what they mean when they say “think outside the box”. Thank you very much

As the LocalTime documentation states, LocalTime is an immutable date-time object that represents a time, often viewed as hour-minute-second. LocalTime has no concept of a day, so 23:59:59 is the maximum value for LocalTime. The loop will only stop when, after several additions to start, it eventually becomes 23:59:59. Alternatively, you can use LocalDateTime to make it aware of the day. For example:
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 12, 24, 10, 12, 0);
        LocalDateTime midnight = LocalDateTime.of(2024, 12, 24, 23, 59, 59);
        for (LocalDateTime t = start; t.isBefore(midnight); t = t.plusMinutes(30)) {
            System.out.println(LocalTime.from(t));
        }

Above code will print what you want and stops normally:
10:12
10:42
...
23:12
23:42


Fine idea (+1). Strictly speaking 23:59:59.999999999 is the max value of LocalTime (also declared as LocalTime.MAX). And strictly speaking you should use 00:00 the next day as midnight, or you loop would not include 23:59:59 in the output if you happen to hit that value.
